# Glassfish 4.0 Server DAS port occupied .Server fails to start

Tags: glassfish-4, netbeans-7.4

I  have Windows 8 .Installed netbeans 7.4 and glassfish 4.0...
When i run a program it says "Could not start glassfish server 4.0 DAs port occupied while server is not running" 
Pl help

Answer (score 0):

Go to service, select server, right click and select add server, Add Server Instance wizard will be opened. select glashfish server and select next button.

In server location give appropriate glashfish location, then select next button. Now Domain wizard will be opened, Give other port number. then click finish.

check is there any application using same port no

1. netstat -na | find "80"
2. netstat -anob